# SQL UPDATE, INSERT or anything else?

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL DB table in a website.  It has few thousand rows of data.  I just added a column and need to add data to this column for row_id 1500 to 5000.  I am thinking of doing this -

```
UPDATE `TableName` SET `Col_New` = 'abc' WHERE `id` = '1500'
```

and repeat this until -

```
UPDATE `TableName` SET `Col_New` = 'xyz' WHERE `id` = '5000'
```

Is this efficient  or is there a better faster way of doing it?  'Am a newbie, hence Will appreciate a nod or any advice.

Comment: You can use `between` as shown in an answer below to update multiple rows at once.  However, what do you want to set the column to?  Your question suggests different rows need different values, but we don't have any way of knowing what they are.

Comment: @Ben could you give some more examples on how you correlate the old `id`s to the new `Col_New` values you want to produce?

Comment: What do you mean by 'faster'?

Comment: If the value you want to update is same then just do it with one statement `UPDATE TableName SET Col_New = 'xyz' WHERE id <= '5000' and id >= 1500`

Comment: @dan1111 yes diff values for diff rows.  They are in excel and I'll use a macro write the UPDATE statement for each row.

Comment: @Mureinik I am using the existing `id` to identify the row to update.

Comment: @sectus - a method that will execute fast as I will be running this as a batch for thousands of rows.

Comment: A join will be faster

Comment: is there some elegant SQL like - `for id = 1500 to 5000 INSERT INTO TableName (Col_New) VALUES ('abc', ....., 'xyz')` or `for id = 1500 to 5000 UPDATE TableName SET Col_New = ('abc', ...., 'xyz')`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BETWEEN` as follow:

```
UPDATE `TableName` SET `Col_New` = 'abc' WHERE `id` BETWEEN '1500' and '5000';
```

If `Col_New` values are different for each row then you should use loop as you have done.

Comment: Just like dan1111 mentioned, it is possible that the OP wants Col_New to be set to different values for each id. If that is the case, individual queries may have to be written or a temporary junction table would have to be created

Comment: @zedfoxus, i agree with you. ans edited. thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @PrisionerRaju It's not same data `'abc'` for rows `1500` to `5000`, it's all diff for each row.

Comment: @zedfoxus +1 for being the first to recognize the need accurately and reply appropriately.

Comment: @PrisonerRaju yes `Col_New` values are diff, but which loop are you recommending pls?

Answer (score 0):

Put your update queries into one transaction

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE `TableName` SET `Col_New` = 'abc' WHERE `id` = '1500';
-- and so on
UPDATE `TableName` SET `Col_New` = 'xyz' WHERE `id` = '5000';
COMMIT;
```

It will be much faster. For transaction engines only - innoDb.

Comment: Why would it be faster? If this were true, then surely all queries should be wrapped up in transactions

Comment: @Strawberry. Every query by default uses it's own transaction. Every transaction has performance overhead. So, making one big transactions reduces this overhead. And it isn't hard to test it by your self, just check it. Also, do not use transactions for 'all queries'. Use transaction to make atomic operations. I am sure this update modifications could be atomic.

Comment: @sectus i can't test it as the table type i see here is myISAM.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient, scalable way would likely be:

**Get your data into a table in the database**

Use MySQL's [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) to do this.

**Update from that table**

```
UPDATE `tableName`
INNER JOIN `sourceValues` ON
   `tableName.id` = `sourceValues.id`
SET `tableName`.`Col_New` = `sourceValues`.`Col_New`
```

Note that I haven't included a `where` clause, because I am assuming that the sourceValues table only includes the values you want to update.  You could, however, add if needed:

```
where `tableName.id` between 1500 and 5000
```

If you are just doing this as a quick hack, then a macro that inserts each row may be the easiest way.  But I would recommend something like this if it is an operation you will be doing a lot, especially if you might want to do it with significantly more values in the future.

Comment: yes, as you say, for recurring w/and/or significantly more values.